# why I can't access the "inner variable" with event binding in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript programming. Below is my code which is quite simple. I just don't know why the `c.calculate()` will alert right number (5), but if clicking on the button, will alert `undefined`. And how to change the codes to let the "click" alert number 5?

```
//testing
var Cal = function(){
    this.x = 5;            
}

Cal.prototype.calculate = function(){
    alert(this.x);
}

Cal.prototype.add_button = function(){
    var mybutton = $("<button id='test'>test</button>").appendTo('body'); // I am using Jquery
    mybutton.bind('click',this.calculate);
}

var c = new Cal();        
c.add_button(); // when click on the 'test' button, will alert "undefined"
c.calculate(); // will alert '5'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a correct context you can use (as soon as you're already using jquery):

```
mybutton.bind('click', $.proxy(this.calculate, this));
```

or

```
mybutton.bind('click', this.calculate.bind(this));
```

The latter's support is limited though (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks said, `this` is pointing to other object than `c`. Try this instead:

```
Cal.prototype.add_button = function(){
    var mybutton = $("<button id='test'>test</button>").appendTo('body'); // I am using Jquery
    var that = this;    //important
    mybutton.bind('click',function(){
        return that.calculate();
    });
}
```

Comment: May be even `return that.calculate();`